# Regular Expression in Python, issue with similar looking results

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a list of strings. This will have some element which will be repeated in a particular way. Let me show this with an example:

```
l1 = ['Test 1 result', 'Test 2 result', 'Test 3 result', 'Test 1 grade result', 'Test 2 grade result', 'Test 3 grade result', 'other items', 'more items which will not have the same pattern']
```

My question is how can I get all elements like **'Test % result'** from my base list excluding others.

Edit: I want this list to be returned

```
l2 = ['Test 1 result', 'Test 2 result', 'Test 3 result']
```

Comment: Try regular expressions?

Comment: it's not clear what you expect. It's better to demonstrate the output you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex :

```
import re

l1 = ['Test 1 result', 'Test 2 result', 'Test 3 result', 'Test 1 grade result',
      'Test 2 grade result', 'Test 3 grade result', 'other items',
      'more items which will not have the same pattern']


l2 = [item for item in l1 if re.match(r'^Test \d+ result$', item)]
print(l2)
```

Answer (score 1):

rdas mentioned using a regular expression. In python this would look something like this:

```py
import re

l2 = []
testResult = re.compile("Test \d result")
for x in l1:
    if testResult.match(x):
        l2.append(x)
```

You can read more about the python regex package here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
And you can use this tool to test regexes: https://regexr.com/

Comment: That number can be 2 or more digits then this fails. Also check for start and end of the string.

Answer (score -1):

```
l2=[]
for name in l1:
    if name[:5]=="Test ":
        i=5
        while name[i].isnumeric():
            i+=1
        if name[i:]==" result":
            l2.append(name)
print(l2)
```